# forcing glassfish to use UDP (config or application code)

Tags: glassfish, udp

Hey guys, I am not very familiar with glassfish, but am attempting to resolve a small issue we are having. It seems that when our application is sending packets over a certain size, glassfish is doing so using TCP. However, we want it to always use UDP.

I am having trouble finding any information regarding if there is some configuration parameter we can change so that it will not do this. Also, I am not sure at what point glassfish begins using TCP. If I was able to figure that out, I bet I could somehow alter the application so that the packets would not reach that size.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am using sailfin and SIP over UDP.

Comment: UDP for what? HTTP, RMI, IIOP (i.e. the native Glassfish protocols) are all TCP. What protocol are you using that would use UDP? Are you using Sailfin and SIP over UDP?

Comment: @WillHartung I will edit with answers to this question. Sorry for not including that in my initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding this information: http://java.net/jira/browse/SAILFIN-2088

It seems that it switches to TCP at 1250. This value is not currently configurable.